# Exporting table data to CSV in php

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I have a code block which when tested in my local wamp server is working fine but when uploaded it to live server which is IIS it is not working, though echo is displaying but csv file is not generating. Here is my code block.
NB: data connection is perfectly working

```
$query =    "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col_one=1";

$result = $conn->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $time = date("Y-m-d");
    $filename = "repot_".$time;
    $fp = fopen("report/$filename.csv", 'w');

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
        echo "Mobile: " . $row["col_one"]. " - Name: " . $row["col_two"]. "<br>";
    }
    fclose($fp);

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: did you check folder permissions?

Comment: how to do that in IIS? I am accessing the server through remote desktop directly.

Comment: check this , hope this help :http://www.kbpublisher.com/kb/setting-up-folder-permissions-in-internet-information-services-%28iis%29_392.html

Comment: It's not the permission issue because all privilege is given to this folder. Still not working. Some code bug, I suppose.

Comment: It could be a problem with directory separator. Try change path to `"report\\$filename.csv"`

Comment: Sadly, no way. I have tried these all ways. Not working. There is something missing in my code it seems, but can't trace that one. Or maybe some bug in my code... :(

Comment: Check the `fopen` and `fputcsv` errors: `fopen() or die('can not create file')`, `fputcsv() or die('can not write to file')`

Comment: Thanks @fusion3k. fopen is having problem. "can not create file"

Comment: allow error reporting to see the exact error (`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`) to see if it is a path error or write perm error. Also use absolute path instead of relative path

Comment: @fusuin3k: Permission denied error (I am using IIS , Windows 2008 Server

Answer (score -1):

I knew it seems weird but maybe the solution is updating:

```
$fp = fopen("report/$filename.csv", 'w');
```

To this:

```
defined('DS') ? NULL : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$fp = fopen('report' . DS . $filename . 'csv', 'w');
```